# Generics fails without Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, generics, jpa, spring-boot

I have this Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@Import(PersistenceConfiguration.class)
public class DAOConfiguration {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Bean
    public ClientDAO clientDAO() {
        SimpleJpaRepository<Client, String> support = this.getSimpleJpaRepository(Client.class);
        return new MySQLClientDAO(support);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Description("Hibernate repository helper")
    protected <T> SimpleJpaRepository<T, String> getSimpleJpaRepository(Class<T> domainClass) {
        return new SimpleJpaRepository<T, String>(domainClass, this.entityManager);
    }

}
```

If i run it with Spring Boot, everything works fine. But if i don't, i get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36 cannot be cast to org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository
    at com.example.movies.domain.config.DAOConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$248dfcc5.getSimpleJpaRepository(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.example.movies.domain.config.DAOConfiguration.clientDAO(DAOConfiguration.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.movies.domain.config.DAOConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$248dfcc5.CGLIB$clientDAO$0(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.example.movies.domain.config.DAOConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$248dfcc5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$96fcb656.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.movies.domain.config.DAOConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$248dfcc5.clientDAO(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
16:31:50.506 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@4ff04845 testClass = ClientDAOTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@75c57e85 testClass = ClientDAOTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.example.movies.domain.config.DAOConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], dirtiesContext [false].
```

Do you know what is happening? I'm soooo confused... Thanks in advance

---

### EDIT

This is the line failing:

```
return new SimpleJpaRepository<T, String>(domainClass, this.entityManager);
```

Comment: Remove `@Bean` and `@Scope` from the `getSimpleJpaRepository` method. Also why on earth are you doing things like this??? Seems like you are trying to work your way around Spring Data JPA instead of using it.

Comment: Because in this case i have only ClientDAO, but if i would have MovieDAO, OtherDAO, then doing it like this way i call that method, and get my SimpleJpaRepositoy for that class.

Comment: I fixed adding enabling proxyTargetClass

Comment: But that isn't the way you should be doing it. You should only be defining an interface (`ClientDao<Client, String>`) and let `@EnableJpaRepositories` create the instances for that. You are basically trying to work around the Spring Data JPA configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say you are approaching this the wrong way, you shouldn't be messing around with the `SimpleJapRepository`. You should use `@EnableJpaRepositories` and let that do the work.

What you should do is create an interface which extends one of the Spring Data repository interfaces and add `@EnableJpaRepository` and basically that is it. No `MySQLClientDAO` just an interface for which you will be given an implementation at runtime.

```
public interface ClientDAO<Client, String> extends JpaRepository {... }
```

Then in your configuration

```
@Configuration
@Import(PersistenceConfiguration.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"package.containing.repository.interfaces"}
public class DAOConfiguration { }
```

And that is basically all you should need.

If you have another repository the only thing you would need to do is add another interface.

```
public interface MovieDAO<Movie, String> extends CrudRepository { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i opted to use SimpleJpaRepository because it gives me some functionality that i don't want to do by myself and extending JpaRepository doesn't help :P

Comment: I don't get that... Because the dynamically created repository is backed by a `SimpleJpaRepository`. So it looks like you are working around the framework or aren't understanding it correctly. What is the thing you need that isn't provided when using the interfaces????

Comment: yes, i think i am not understanding it correctly. i read documentation but i understand always the same, i mean, I have my ClientDAO interface which extends JpaReposity. What you are trying to say is that just by putting @EnableJpaRepository in DaoConfiguration spring will create a ClientDAO implementation using SimpleJpaRepository? Because right now i am creating the implementation manually, and as you see, using SimpleJpaRepository as functionality support (just to not have to write save method again, for example, it provides me implementations for that method). Am i wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you are wrong... That is already provided for you. The `JpaRepository` extends `PagingAndSortingRepository` which extends `CrudRepository`. The latter already has a save method. This save method will be passed on the the `SimpleJpaRepository`. You don't have to do anything yourself, Spring Data JPA already takes care of all that. The only thing you need to do is extend one of those interfaces (depending on your needs). So basically you can ditch your implementations, leave the interfaces, cleanup your config and go.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience! I think i got it and i made it work as you said!